# Showing that f'=0 implies constant f on an open star set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the following statement (definition was included in the problem). It was on my midterm and it was supposedly easy but I still don't know what to do even though my final is tomorrow. Any help is greatly appreciated.

We say a set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is star-shaped if it satisfies the following property: there exists a point $x_0 \in E$ such that for any $x$ in $E$, the segment $\{(1-t)x_0+tx; t \in [0,1]\}$ is in $E$. Prove that if $E$ is an open star-shaped subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f: E \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable function and $f'=0$ on $E$, then $f$ is a constant on E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use (a suitable generalization of) the mean value theorem to show that 
$$f(x) - f(x_0) = 0 \ \forall x \in E,$$
where $E$ is star shaped with respect to $x_0$.

You could also consider using the MVT to show that all of the component functions are constant. Either way, I believe that the MVT will be the way to go.